# Woocommerce Single Product Price Slider

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, slider, price

Good day. I need to make price slider for single product page like this one:

http://bulka.ua/product/kofe-paketirovannyj/kofe-3-v-1-original-banka-maccoffee-160-20g-kofe-3-v-1-original-banka-maccoffee-160-20g, so than i change it, it changes the price.

How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance!